# Thread at language level

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm reading about threads and in many books is said that Java support threads at language level and at a high-level trough the `java.util.concurrent` package.

What does it meaning supporting thread at language level?

I think Erlang is a language that support thread at language level...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To have threading supported at the language level means that the language provides first-class support for multi-threading, as opposed to just providing second-class support via class libraries.

In Java, threading is supported at the language level with the `synchronized` and `volatile` keywords. Using monitors and volatile fields are relatively low-level threading constructs - higher level constructs, such as generic Locks, Barriers, ThreadPools, Concurrent collections are found in the `java.util.concurrent` package, along with low level atomic operations.

Threading in Java is more than a few keywords in the language. The [Java Memory Model](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/) mandates the results of multi-threaded memory access, such as when changes by one thread are visible to other threads. This ensures correctly written threaded programs function as intended regardless of the underlying architecture (instruction re-ordering, cache-coherence polices etc..)

The original java class library provides threading support with `java.lang.Thread`, representing a thread, and since JDk 1.2, `java.lang.ThreadLocal`, representing thread-local variables. The original JDK also includes an abstract notion  of an executable object - `java.lang.Runnable`. The concurrency utils extend this with `Callable` and `Future`, which make creating asynchronous results much simpler than it would be coding with just the low level constructs.

While you can make do with `volatile`, `synchronized` and `Runnable` (as many did prior to JDK 1.5) the classes provided by the concurrency utils make writing threaded programs much easier and with a greater chance of them being correct.

Answer (score 0):

There is java.lang.Thread and java.util.concurrent, which contains some sugar like semaphors, executors, blockingQueues  etc.
Seems like (i don;t know for sure) that all the classes in util.concurrent are based on java.lang.Thread, so java.lang.Thread is as low-level as you can get in java. Meaning that java.util.concurrent is high-level comparing to Thread.

Answer (score 0):

It means that **it has a programmer-friendly abstraction** over threads (see `java.lang.Thread`). It supports simple yet powerful synchronization with `synchronized`keyword. It also has great utilities for thread pooling, concurrency, locking etc. in `java.util.concurrent`.

Answer (score 0):

That means threads are part of the Java language specification as opposed to thread libraries in C, for example.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK `synchronized` and `volatile` are the only concurrent language features present in Java. Everything else is just a library of wrappers for common synchronization mechanisms (semaphores, locks, mutexes, etc).

Answer (score 0):

There is a fairly long chapter in the [Java **Language** Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/memory.html) - a strong indicator, that threading is supported through by the language itself. The most obvious Java language elements are the keyword *synchronized* and *volatile*. Another supporting element is the special effect of the `Thread` class:

> Threads are represented by the Thread class. The only way for a user to create a thread is to create an object of this class; each thread is associated with such an object. A thread will start when the start() method is invoked on the corresponding Thread object.